# How does one remove a MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, media-player

I have too many MediaPlayers. What is the accepted method to remove them from memory so that I can create more? Changing the filesource doesn't seem to work, I need rid of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try the [`MediaPlayer.release()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release%28%29) function.